# Illegal column names error yet column names are legal

Tags: r, r-caret

Wondering why I get this error. I can only reproduce it if I make the levels within my data frame illegal column names, but why does it work in the RF implementation?

Thinking about using ranger as it seems to run faster.

```
library(caret)
library(ranger)
library(randomForest)

df <- data.frame(class = c(rep(c('A','B'), 10)), var1 = runif(20, 0,10), var2 = runif(20, 0,20), var3 = c(rep(c(' A','1 B', 'C'), 6), 'D','D'))
df

CTRL <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                     number = 2, 
                     repeats = 1, 
                     verboseIter = TRUE,
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     returnResamp = "final",
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

ranger_model <- caret::train(class ~ .,
                              df,
                              method = "ranger",
                              trControl = CTRL,
                              preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                              metric="ROC",
                              tuneGrid = expand.grid(.mtry=c(1,2)))

rf_model <- caret::train(class ~ .,
                              df,
                              method = "rf",
                              trControl = CTRL,
                              preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                              metric="ROC",
                              tuneGrid = expand.grid(.mtry=c(1,2)))

ranger_model
rf_model
```

Ranger Output:

```
+ Fold1.Rep1: mtry=1 
model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: mtry=1 Error in parse.formula(formula, data) : 
Error: Illegal column names in formula interface. Fix column names or use alternative interface in ranger.
```

Also, when I check the documentation for ranger that produces the error, I'm not understanding why this evaluates to TRUE, because when I run the code on my DF, I don't get the same result:

```
## Error if illegal column name
if (!all(make.names(independent_vars[!interaction_idx]) == independent_vars[!interaction_idx])) {
stop("Error: Illegal column names in formula interface. Fix column names or use alternative interface in ranger.")
}
```

https://github.com/cran/ranger/blob/master/R/formula.R

When I run it on my df:

```
formula <- 'class ~ .'
data <- df

f <- as.formula(formula)
t <- terms(f, data = data)

## Get dependent var(s)
response <- data.frame(eval(f[[2]], envir = data))
colnames(response) <- deparse(f[[2]])

## Get independent vars
independent_vars <- attr(t, "term.labels")
interaction_idx <- grepl(":", independent_vars)

## Error if illegal column name
if (!all(make.names(independent_vars[!interaction_idx]) == independent_vars[!interaction_idx])) {
    print("Error: Illegal column names in formula interface. Fix column names or use alternative interface in ranger.")
}

> !all(make.names(independent_vars[!interaction_idx]) == independent_vars[!interaction_idx])
## [1] FALSE
```

Is it because the factor columns are made into a 1-hot encoded matrix that uses the factor level as the column name? Again, not sure why it would work in RF and not ranger.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed in caret 6.0-77. In your example, you'll have to add the `splitrule` parameter to `tuneGrid`:

```
library(caret)
library(ranger)
library(randomForest)

df <- data.frame(class = c(rep(c('A','B'), 10)), var1 = runif(20, 0,10), var2 = runif(20, 0,20), var3 = c(rep(c(' A','1 B', 'C'), 6), 'D','D'))
df

CTRL <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                     number = 2, 
                     repeats = 1, 
                     verboseIter = TRUE,
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     returnResamp = "final",
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

ranger_model <- caret::train(class ~ .,
                             df,
                             method = "ranger",
                             trControl = CTRL,
                             preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                             metric="ROC",
                             tuneGrid = expand.grid(.mtry=c(1,2), .splitrule="gini"))

rf_model <- caret::train(class ~ .,
                         df,
                         method = "rf",
                         trControl = CTRL,
                         preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                         metric="ROC",
                         tuneGrid = expand.grid(.mtry=c(1,2)))

ranger_model
rf_model
```